# Least Square Means problems in R

Tags: r, lsmeans

My data looks like this with plots as rows and with different Ellenberg values as columns together with `Year`, Forest (`Skov`) and Forest type (`Skovtype`).

My data are from 4 different years (1993, 1998, 2005 and 2016).

[image]

I have some problems with the lsmeans function my script looks like this:

```
ellenberg_LM <- read.csv2("Gns. Ellenberg1.csv")
```

Converting year from integer to factor

```
levels(ellenberg_LM$Year)
ellenberg_LM$Year <- factor(ellenberg_LM$Year)
```

Ellenberg L - LM

```
LLM<-lm(Gennemsnit.af.L_Ellenberg ~ Year + Skov + Skov*Year + Skovtype + Skovtype*Year,
        data=ellenberg_LM)
```

LS-means

```
install.packages("lsmeans")
library(lsmeans)
lsmeans(LLM,~ Year, data = ellenberg_LM)
```

My output looks like this, with NA’s for 1993 in the first example. But if I leave out the interaction with `Skov*Year` and `Skovtype*Year` `R` estimates lsmeans for all years like the last example.

[image]

My question is then; do you know what I have done wrong to get the NA’s or do I miss something? Because I want the calculate lsmeans for all years with the interactions.

Comment: It does give you a warning. Perhaps you might be better off on R-help although if you post there I would include the output from lm as well.

Comment: Are all Skov=="H" and all Skovtype=="L" in 1993?

Comment: No, Skov can be R or H because there are two different forest in the study. Skovtype can be L (deciduous forest), N (coniferous forest), A (open areas) or U (not with). And Year can be 1993, 1998, 2005 and 2016.

Comment: I did not ask what "can be" but what is the case in 1993 but is not the case in all the other years. Missing data combinations might be a problem, as mentioned in the answer by rvl. She/He also hints to way of finding the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `NA` is there because the predicted value is not estimable at certain combinations of the three factors -- hence still not estimable after averaging over the levels of two of those factors. This is probably due to there being no data at certain factor combinations (empty cells in the data). When you fitted a simpler model, those predictions became estimable because some interaction effects no longer need to be estimated.

If any of the interaction effects are significant, you probably should not be estimating those marginal means anyway (that's why there is a warning message). Look at some interaction plots (e.g., using `lsmip` with the interaction model) to visualize what is going on and to see if it is sensible to average the predictions together. See a statistical consultant if this stuff is confusing to you.

By the way, the `data` argument is not necessary in the `lsmeans` call.